# WCF suddenly stopped working with "does not have an implementation" when it does?

Tags: wpf, wcf

This had been working well...But stopped.

Why?

Error Message:

> Method 'GetAllRx' in type 'Nova.ClientProxy.NovaDataService' from assembly 'Nova.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetAllRx' in type 'Nova.ClientProxy.NovaDataService' from assembly 'Nova.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Here is the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INovaDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<View_rx> GetAllRx(DateTime tencounter, String groupid);
}
```

Here is its implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<View_rx> GetAllRx(DateTime tencounter, String groupid)
{
        using (var context = new Nova.Data.Data())
        {
            var query = from rx in context.GetAllRx(tencounter, groupid)
                        where rx.Rxtype == "Rx"
                        select rx;

            var result = context.CreateDetachedCopy(query.ToList());
            return result;
        }
}
```

This is implemented under IIS and stopped working after a recent update.

Comment: Have you been changing the interface in this recent update? Usually this exception is thrown when you have the interface and the class implementing it in two different assemblies. The interface has changed, but the class implementing it isn't updated, therefore it doesn't really implement the new interface.

Comment: @DamirArh Yes. But the above implementation is in the class. What eventually fixed this was removing the implementation from the class, then letting VS2010 create the implementation stub itself, then adding the body to the stub. I don't know why VS couldn't find the existing implementation.